# Docker with systemctl

Tags: docker, dockerfile, systemctl

I created a dockerfile based on Ubuntu 20.04 that changes .bashrc and clones repository from github and starts instalation. (In repository exists file server_install.sh that install the program.)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04  
USER root  
LABEL maintainer="zarooba"  
ENV TZ=Europe/Warsaw  
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive   
ADD aamks_bashrc.txt /root  
RUN touch /root/.bashrc && cat /root/aamks_bashrc.txt >> /root/.bashrc  
RUN apt-get update  
RUN apt-get install -y python3  
RUN apt-get install -y git  
WORKDIR /usr/local  
RUN git clone https://github.com/aamks/aamks.git  
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/aamks/installer/server_install.sh"]  
RUN apt-get update -y && \  
    apt-get -y install sudo && \  
    apt-get install -y systemd   
CMD /usr/local/aamks/installer/server_install.sh
```

Instalation starts and everytihing is ok, but at some point during instalation there's a bug:

```
Bug with systemctl: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

systemctl is installed as described in dockefile. I don't have an idea how to get rid out of this bug.

Lines of file server_install.sh that contain systemctl:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gearman-job-server.service
```

Comment: For the most part `systemctl` doesn't work in Docker at all.  I'd avoid installing Systemd in a container (it is very heavyweight and invasive), along with git (there are several operational problems around credentials and updates) and sudo (unnecessary in Docker), and also most paths to running containers don't use a `.bashrc` file.  Can you install the software by hand, without using the installer, and set the `CMD` to run it as a foreground process (without `systemctl` or any sort of init system involved)?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I corrected things that you sugested and it worked. It was supposed to be installed with installer, but it wasn't the biggest problem in all of this.

Answer (score 0):

All the docker RUN scripts will start in a container where you can not control the PID 1. It is actually the script that you try to execute in it. If it would be another service then it is sometimes helpful to start/stop the process in each stp.

```
RUN dbctl start ; execdb -c "CREATE USER"; dbctl stop
```

There is a workaround by using the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script which intercepts the systemctl executions and that can start/stop the required services as needed as well. That allows you to run the VM-orientered "server_install" in a container (without patching it)

Comment: Thank you. I needed to restart service in server_install and I replaced systemctl with service restart. And it worked.